# How do I include a partial from a directory below a wordpress theme directory?

Tags: theme-development, themes, directory

I have 3 themes set up right now and I need them all to inherit partials from the same source in order to update all three themes at the exact same time when I change any of those partials.

I'm seeing that include/require (../../../includes/vital/partial.php); doesn't work from within single.php or any other other theme template file. the error I get is:

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../../includes/vital/partial.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.8/lib/php') in /Users/insertusername/Documents/Code/Projects/wordpress/wordpress-1/wp-content/themes/flowerz-mobile/single.php on line 7

How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever use relative paths in wordpress. use `require(ABSPATH .'your path relative to wordpress root')`. There are also other useful constants and API for that but selecting one will depend on where exactly do yo want your common code to be.

At the minimum it will make it easier to understand from the error message which file exactly is failing to open.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that just doing include('include/vital/partial.php'); worked. This seems to work from wordpress root by default. I tried using an aboslute path function within the include function and I was seeing all kinds of errors. What is the advantage of using an abs path function vs. doing it the way I just described? And what's the proper way to use an abs_path function within another function like include?

Comment: what is included in `include('include/vital/partial.php')` depends also on the php settings, the default folders in which it looks for files http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path, so might actually end including something that you did not intend to.

Comment: Ok cool. That's good to know. Now, how can I get something like include(get_bloginfo('wpurl') . 'includes/vital/partial.php');    to work? I've been searching around and reading a lot but I'm not seeing an answer. Thanks!

Comment: for example https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_root, and there are probably more APIs of this kind that do not pop into my head right now